# MVC 4 URL generating from Routes with Razor @Html.RouteLink

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have problems with generating URL with `Html.RouteLink` method using route.

My routes:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "DefaultPage",
            url: "",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "MessagesIndex",
            url: "{controller}/{page}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Messages", action = "Index", page = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

My controller(MessagesController) index method header:

```
public ActionResult Index(int page = 0)
```

And link generation:

```
@Html.RouteLink("Messages", "MessagesIndex")
```

I already tried ActionLink and Action...

EDIT: Sloved. Glimpse helped and MSDN. **Its very important order of routes too.**

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain what problems you are having?
Maybe this will work:

```
@Url.Action("Index", "Messages")
```

Comment: I need full link generation, becouse i want to get class="selected" when im in it. Link just does not being generated. And this one does not work eather.

Comment: None. Empty string. Sometimes it works, but generates from other route.